# Why I cannot get a value from android?

Tags: java, android, jsp

In my main.xml I set two EditText to get num1 and num 2, on Buntto to run the add operation

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="num1"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="+" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="num2"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="=" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="add"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final int UPDATE_TEXT = 1;
    private EditText etx1;
    private EditText etx2;
    private TextView result;
    Button getresult;
    private double num1;
    private double num2;
    private double resultnum;
    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case UPDATE_TEXT:
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String url = "http://localhost:8080/test/index.jsp?num1="
                                + num1 + "&" + "num2=" + num2;
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                        try {
                            httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                result.setText(new Double(resultnum).toString());
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        };
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etx1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
        etx2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        getresult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        getresult.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(etx1.getText().toString());
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(etx2.getText().toString());
                resultnum = num1 + num2;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Message message = new Message();
                        message.what = UPDATE_TEXT;
                        handler.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And my index.jsp:

```
<body>
<h1>Using GET Method to Read Form Data</h1>
<ul>
    <li><p>
            <b>Num1:</b>
            <%=request.getParameter("num1")%>
        </p></li>
    <li><p>
            <b>Num2:</b>
            <%=request.getParameter("num2")%>
        </p></li>
    <li><p>
            <b>result:</b>
            <%=request.getParameter("num2")+request.getParameter("num1")%>
        </p></li>
</ul>
```

When I navigate to http://localhost:8080/test/ in Chrome I see `num1 = null, num2 = null, result = nullnull`. Why are the values not properly filled in?

Comment: You do know that `localhost` is the hostname of your actual device. Unless you run the server on your phone, this hostname is not pointing to the right server. Change it to your server's IP or hostname instead.

Comment: After i change to 127.0.0.1 i cannot get value too

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the same as `localhost`. They both point to the local device and ***NOT*** to the server running on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is running on a localhost and so your device cannot connect to the server. Set your server to run on `0.0.0.0` and then in your code, change the url to the IP Address of your computer instead of localhost. To find your IP Address, go to your command prompt and type ipconfig. Then look for your ipv4 address.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't enter the onCLick method and that's why your values are always null. Convert your code to this one:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final int UPDATE_TEXT = 1;
    private EditText etx1;
    private EditText etx2;
    private TextView result;
    Button getresult;
    private double num1;
    private double num2;
    private double resultnum;
    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case UPDATE_TEXT:
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            String url = "http://localhost:8080/test/index.jsp?num1="
                        + num1 + "&" + "num2=" + num2;
                            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                            try {
                                httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    result.setText(new Double(resultnum).toString());
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
             }
        };
    };

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etx1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
    etx2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    getresult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    View.OnClickListener buttonHandler= new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(etx1.getText().toString());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(etx2.getText().toString());
            resultnum = num1 + num2;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Message message = new Message();
                    message.what = UPDATE_TEXT;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    };

    getresult.setOnClickListener(buttonHandler);
  }
}
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: when i copy this code to eclipse , show the error "buttonHandler cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: My fault - you should put the line `getresult.setOnClickListener(buttonHandler);` after the definition of it - look at the update of my post